# Finding the integral of a radical function?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I had to create a problem in Calculus, and since I'm terrible at finding the limits of a definite integral, I decided it would be good to practice with that. So I created this:

> Two waffles are being heated in a slightly broken kitchen toaster. At time $t = 0$, their temperature was $0^{\circ}\;{\rm C}$. At a time $t = x$, they popped out. The toaster is built to only pop when it detects that the first slot has reached a temperature of $33.73^{\circ}\;{\rm C}$. The rate at which the first waffle was heated is defined by:
>
> $f(x) = \sqrt{5x}$
>
> The rate at which the other is heated is defined by:
>
> $g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{11x}{2}}$
>
> 1. Find the time x at which they popped.
> 2. Find the temperature of the second waffle at $t = x$.
> 3. On the interval $0 \leq t \leq x$, find the time at which the two waffles were the same temperature.
> 4. Write, but do not evaluate, an equation that would return the time at which a food of any starting temperature $q$ would pop out of the toaster.

I used the square root operations so it would make sense with the problem, but now I'm confused as to how to take the integral of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a \sqrt b$. We use that fact, and the power rule,  below:

$$\int \sqrt {5x} \;dx = \int \sqrt 5 \sqrt x\,dx = \sqrt 5\int x^{1/2}\;dx = \sqrt 5 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot x^{3/2} + C = \dfrac{2\sqrt{5x^3}}{3} + C$$

Can you do the similarly for the $g(x)$, knowing that $\sqrt{\frac{11x}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac {11}{2}}x^{1/2}$?

Comment: That's much easier than the substitution rule I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Jack!

Comment: If you are mentioning the fact that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$, you might as well mention the fact that $\sqrt{a} = a^{1/2}$ and $\int C x \;dx = C \int x \;dx$ (where $C \in \mathbb{R}$)